# patch formgroup which doesn't exist at compilation time

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm trying to implement a sub form example following [this](https://www.dotnetsurfers.com/blog/2020/10/11/3-approaches-for-implementing-nested-forms-in-angular/) blog post (approach 1). In the blog post, there is also a stackblitz example. The example uses angular 10, I use angular 16.

The scenario is the following.

I have this simple form:

```
profileForm = this.fb.group({
    firstName: ['', Validators.required],
    lastName: [''],
    aliases: this.fb.array([this.fb.control('')]),
  });
```

In an other component I pass this form as a parent form via `Input@` and add an `address` group to it:

```
this.parentFormGroup.addControl(
      'address',
      this.fb.group({
        street: ['', Validators.required],
        city: [''],
        state: [''],
        zip: [''],
      })
    );
```

This approach works. The controls of the sub form are displayed, also validation works.

Now, in the main form component (where the `profileForm` sits), I want to patch this `address` formgroup.

In the blog post this is done simply via `patchValue`:

```
updateProfile() {
    this.profileForm.patchValue({
      firstName: 'Nancy',
      address: {
        street: '123 Drew Street',
      },
    });
  }
```

In the blog post example this works. I assume, because it uses angular 10. But in angular 16 I get an error:

`Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'address' does not exist in type 'Partial<{ firstName: string | null; lastName: string | null; aliases: (string | null)[]; }>'`.

Of course there is no `address` property. It is added at runtime.

But I'm able to do this:

```
this.profileForm.patchValue({ firstName: 'Nancy' });

(this.profileForm.get('address') as any as FormGroup)?.patchValue({
  street: '123 Drew Street',
});
```

It works, but is for me a little bit awkward with this double cast.

Is there really no other way to do this, without declaring the `address` form group on the `profileForm`?

Comment: I would suggest you patch value in the component itself where you have defined profileForm, rather than patching it in the some other component. Please let me know if this will help.

Comment: I patch it in the main component, where the profileForm is declared. But see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found a convenient way:

```
(this.profileForm as FormGroup).patchValue({
      firstName: 'Nancy',
      address: { street: '123 Drew Street' },
    });
```

With casting the `profileForm` to `FormGroup` it becomes to a general formgroup and doesn't care about the missing `address` property.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the stricted type of formGroup is a "big headache", but you can use [interfaces in the way](https://angular.io/guide/typed-forms#optional-controls-and-dynamic-groups)

```
interface AddressForm {
  street: FormControl<string|null>;
  city: FormControl<string|null>;
  state: FormControl<string|null>;
  zip: FormControl<string|null>;
}
interface ProfileForm{
  firstName: FormControl<string|null>;
  lastName: FormControl<string|null>;
  aliases:FormArray<FormControl<string|null>>;
  address?:FormGroup<AddressForm>;
}
```

And use, e.g.

```
  form=new FormGroup<ProfileForm>(
    {
      firstName: new FormControl(''),
      lastName: new FormControl(''),
      aliases: new FormArray<FormControl<string|null>>([]),
    }
  )

  //when we add address
  addAdress()
  {
    this.form.addControl("address",new FormGroup<AddressForm>({
      street: new FormControl(''),
      city: new FormControl(''),
      state: new FormControl(''),
      zip: new FormControl(''),
    }))
  }
```

See a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-swulta?file=src%2Fmain.ts)